# Which method should i use to replace my basic ajax request in phonegap

Tags: javascript, ajax, cordova, phonegap

Hello i want to build a hybrid app out of my website code but the problem is i read Phonegap doesn't support my ajax request do you know any alternative and could you share it with me?

My Ajax request:

```
$.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "http://quantivorquali.de/amk.Neusocken.php",
          data:{nam_ersteller:nam_ersteller, punkte:punkte, text:text, benachrichtigung:benachrichtigung, status:status},
            success: function(data){
              window.location = "http://quantivorquali.de/amk.html";
          }


      })
```

Answer (score 0):

Phonegap supports ajax requests but you will need to do the following.

Makesure your php files have the following line at the top of each php file - this allows the app to access to the php file:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
```

The success result in your script will redirect the app to an external website outside the app unless you use the relevant plugins for Phonegap.

You may need to add:

```
 cordova-plugin-whitelist
 cordova-plugin-inappbrowser
```

to your config.xml file along with

```
<access origin="*" />   
<allow-navigation href="*" />
<allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="tel:*" />
<allow-intent href="sms:*" />
<allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
<allow-intent href="geo:*" />
<allow-navigation href="https://*.someURL.com/*" />
```

Does the following work?

hello.php:

```
 <?php 
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); 
    echo 'Hello World';
 ?>
```

Ajax:

```
 $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "https://www.exampleURL.com/hello.php",
      dataType:"html",
      data:"some=string",
          success: function(data){
             alert(data)
          }
  })
```

Comment: could you explain what this steps are doing? Because i tried it this way and it doesnt work

Comment: i've added a script you could try..see if that progresses things?

Comment: No it doesnt work i think i have some errors in my phonegap program i will fix them and come back later thx for your help